# Express res.locals and pug not working as expected

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I have the following function in my app.js to make the user-id available to pug templates.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.session.userId;
  next();
});
```

When logged in I have access to the id. But when not logged in my conditional in my pug template is not working. Here is my code in my pug template

```
if {currentUser}
    //do something
else
   //do something else.
```

The `else` part doesn't fire. I've logged the variable `currentUser` and it is an `object`. When I use `JSON.stringify({currentUser})` from the pug template it outputs `{}`

When logged in `currentUser` returns a string id, when logged out `currentUser` returns an empty object. Both pass the `if{currentUser}` clause.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your `if` check in pug template:

`if {currentUser}` will always evaluate to true. Your `if {currentUser}` translates to `if({})` when `currentUser` is undefined, which evaluates to `true`

This is because `{}` is a `truthy` value. When *coerced* to `Boolean` it evaluates to `true`.

```js
if ({}) console.log('yes')

console.log(Boolean({}))
```

Change it to `if currentUser` (without the braces)